# Return angular datatable on angular datatable rowCallback function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatable

I've an `angular datatable` with nested data and I'm trying to create another datatable on row click function.. `rowCallBack` function of parent datatable.

This is my outer datatable html;

```
<table id="tblEmailsByCase" datatable="" dt-options="dtCaseOptions" dt-columns="dtCaseColumns" dt-instance="dtCaseInstance" class="display table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <!-- THIS TABLE IS GENERATED DYNAMICALLY -->
</table>
```

here is how I'm generating datatable;

```
    // adding btn column to list

    if($scope.lstEmailsByCases[i].users != null && $scope.lstEmailsByCases[i].users.length > 0 )
    {
        $scope.lstEmailsByCases[i].btn = '<button id="' + 'btn' + i + '">+</button>';
    }

// creating table's column..

    $scope.dtCaseInstance = {};
    $scope.dtCaseOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource($scope.lstEmailsByCases)
        .withOption('data', $scope.lstEmailsByCases) //pass data source here
        .withOption('dataSrc', '')
        .withOption('rowCallback', rowCallbackCases)
        .withOption('createdRow', createdRowCases)

    //define columns
    $scope.dtCaseColumns = [
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('btn').withTitle(''), //this is to show the '+' button
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('caseId').withTitle('Case Id'),


    ];

//CALLED WHEN ROW IS CREATED
function createdRowCases(row, data, dataIndex) {
    // Recompiling so we can bind Angular directive
    $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
}

//HERE IT IS CALLED WHENEVER ROW IS CLICKED
function rowCallbackCases(tabRow, data, dataIndex) {
    if(tabRow.cells[0].firstChild != null)
        {
            $(tabRow).unbind('click');
            $(tabRow).on('click', function() {

                $(this).find('.a1-icon').toggleClass('fa-rotate-180');
                var tr = $(tabRow);
                var table = $scope.dtCaseInstance.DataTable;
                var row = table.row(tr);

                if (row.child.isShown()) {
                    // This row is already open - close it
                    row.child.hide();
                    tr.removeClass('shown');
                    tabRow.cells[0].firstChild.innerHTML = "+"; //change button value to +
                } else if (typeof row.child(formatCaseUsersTable(row.data())) != "undefined") {
                    // Open this row
                    row.child(formatCaseUsersTable(row.data())).show();
                    tr.addClass('shown');
                    tabRow.cells[0].firstChild.innerHTML = "-"; //change button value to -
                }

            });
        }
}
```

Its working perfectly fine and generating datatable like this;

[image]

Now I'm trying to generate another datatable on `+` button click.. so this is what I'm doing in `formatCaseUsersTable` function that is calling from `rowCallBack` function of this datatable.. here is that function;

```
//CALLED TO CREATE SUB GRID
function formatCaseUsersTable(d) {

    //if detail does not exist
    if (typeof d.users == "undefined") return;

    //defining table
    var html2 = '<table id="tblCaseUsers" datatable="" dt-options="dtCaseUsersOptions" dt-columns="dtCaseUsersColumns" dt-instance="dtCaseUsersInstance" class="display table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">';

    $scope.dtCaseUsersInstance = {};
    $scope.dtCaseUsersOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource(d.users)
        .withOption('data', d.users) //pass data source here
        .withOption('dataSrc', '')
        .withOption('rowCallback', rowCallbackCaseUsers)
        .withOption('createdRow', createdRowCaseUsers)

    //define columns
    $scope.dtCaseUsersColumns = [
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('btn').withTitle(''), //this is to show the '+' button
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('userId').withTitle('User Id'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('userName').withTitle('User Name'),


    ];

  //add button in each row.. this button will be used to show user that the row is expandable
    for (i = 0; i < d.users.length; i++) {
        if(d.users[i].emailsDetail != null && d.users[i].emailsDetail.length > 0 )
        {
            d.users[i].btn = '<button id="' + 'btn' + i + '">+</button>';
        }
    }

    return html2;
}
```

but it is not working accordingly.. this is html created on `+` button click..

[image]

when I check generated html, table definition is there like this;

[image]

But it does not show in grid and doesn't have any columns detail.

Anyone have idea what I'm missing??

Comment: I don't like the idea of mixing AngularJS together with jQuery here in your example, but still it looks like you are simply returning `html2` string in your  `formatCaseUsersTable` method without compiling it, so angularjs could attach `datatable` directive to it. [Can you try returning something like `return $compile(angular.element(html2))($scope);` and see if it helps?](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

Comment: Have you tried the proposed solution?

Comment: @StanislavKvitash sorry for late response... was a little bit busy..

Comment: O Man... this did magic.. *return $compile(angular.element(html2))($scope);* Thank you..make it answer so I can mark it...

Comment: Great it helped you, added as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we can see from your code - `formatCaseUsersTable` method simply returns `html2` as a string, without [compiling it](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler), so AngularJS could attach `datatable` [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) to the `table` [element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element). You have to use [`$compile` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) to compile the string into template, so this should work in your case:

```
function formatCaseUsersTable(d) {
    //..

    //defining table
    var html2 = '<table id="tblCaseUsers" datatable="" dt-options="dtCaseUsersOptions" dt-columns="dtCaseUsersColumns" dt-instance="dtCaseUsersInstance" class="display table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">';
    //....

    return $compile(angular.element(html2))($scope);
}
```